# Polynomial fit has small coefficients

Tags: fitting, polynomials

I'm attempting to fit the positive domain part of an odd polynomial to even polynomials using the `Fit` function, and I get incredibly tiny coefficients that are clearly wrong. Now, I've read the "possible issues" section of the documentation that mentions this exact problem, and I have attempted the solution they advise (shifting and scaling your basis set), to no avail. Is there any recourse within *Mathematica*? I've tried the other fitting functions, with similar results.

```
Fit[Transpose[{Table[i^3, {i, 0, 10, 0.01}], Range[0, 10, 0.01]}], {x^2, x^4, x^6}, x]

(* Out: (0.0000714209) x^2 + (-1.5437*10^-10) x^4 + (9.69696*10^-17) x^6 *)
```

Comment: You're trying to approximate something with a vertical tangent at the origin with the monomial basis. Such things don't end well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.

Comment: I'm in favor of closing it as off topic since it was a simple mistake (and I got my answer anyway), but it was a syntax error. I understand the math just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### $x^{3}$

If you're trying to fit $x^3$ with $a x^2 + b x^4 + c x^6$, with your current setup you're fitting the range rather then function.  i.e. you're submitting:  `{{f[x[1]], x[1]},...}` when you want to supply:
`{{ x[1], f[x[1]]},...}`

Try:

```
Fit[Table[{i, i^3}, {i, 0, 10, 1/100}], {x^2, x^4, x^6}, x]
```

---

### $x^{1/3}$

If you're really trying to fit $x^{1/3}$ (not technically an odd polynomial), as J.M. points out in his comment, you won't get there with $a x^2 + b x^4 + c x^6$.  You can try: $a x^{1/2} + b x^{1/4} + c x^{1/6}$:

```
soln= Fit[Table[{i^3, i}, {i, 0, 10, 1/100}], {x^(1/2), x^(1/4), x^(1/6)}, x]
```

Landing on:

> -0.88736 x^(1/6) + 1.80165 x^(1/4) + 0.0853975 Sqrt[x]

[image: fitPlot]

with deviation plot:

[image: deviationPlot]

Comment: Actually, if he's trying to approximate the cube root function, then that's the right table. His choice of approximation method is another kettle of fish altogether.

Comment: All the same, this seems to have solved my problem. I flipped the values! Thanks, both of you.

Comment: He said odd polynomial so I assumed he was trying to fit $x^3$ with $a x^2 + b x^4 + c x^6$.